# preg_split in unicode mode: delim_capture not working?

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I'm trying to use a regex to split a chunk of Chinese text into sentences. For my purposes, sentence delimiters are:

- the fullwidth full stop 。(0x3002)
- the fullwidth question mark ？(0xFF1F)
- the fullwidth exclamation mark ！(0xFF01)

Now, let's say my $str is this:
`$str = "你好。你好吗？ 我是程序员，不太懂这个我问题，希望大家能够帮忙！一起加油吧！";`

I use preg_split with these parameters:

```
$str2 = preg_split("/([\x{3002}\x{FF01}\x{FF1F}])/u",$str,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

$str2 is now an array that looks like this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "你好" [1]=> string(9) "你好吗" [2]=> string(91) " 我是程序员，不太懂这个我问题，希望大家能够帮忙！一起加油吧！" }
```

However, the expected output is:

```
[0] "你好。" 
[1] "你好吗？"
[2] "我是程序员，不太懂这个我问题，希望大家能够帮忙！"
[3] "一起加油吧！"
```

As you can see, there are two problems: this does not process exclamation marks properly, and second, my fullwidth full stop and fullwidth question marks vanish. I'd expect delim_capture to keep them. I've been looking at this code for so long I can't possibly figure out what the problem is anymore. I would very much appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex code should be like this to be able to capture string + delimiter:

```
$str = "你好。你好吗？ 我是程序员，不太懂这个我问题，希望大家能够帮忙！一起加油吧！";
$arr = preg_split("/\s*([^\x{3002}\x{FF01}\x{FF1F}]+[\x{3002}\x{FF01}\x{FF1F}]\s*)/u",
                  $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
var_dump($arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 array(4) {
  [0]=> string(9)  "你好。"
  [1]=> string(13) "你好吗？ "
  [2]=> string(72) "我是程序员，不太懂这个我问题，希望大家能够帮忙！"
  [3]=> string(18) "一起加油吧！"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `$limit` parameter to [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split).

> array preg_split ( string $pattern , string $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int $flags = 0 ]] )

As a result, you're passing `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` (2) + `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` (1) = `3` as the `$limit`. That's why it's stopping at three.

Add `null` as the `$limit` parameter, and you're in good shape.

```
preg_split($pattern, $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

Comment: Ahhhh, of course...this still puts the delimiter in a separate string though, but if I use the regex provided by @anubhava that's solved, too. Thanks a million!

Comment: Uummm your documentation paste shows that `$limit` is expected to be an integer, but you are advising the use of `null`.  `null` will not leave developers "in good shape" any more.