# How can I get PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE to work with utf-8 Chinese?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [preg_split in unicode mode: delim_capture not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114166/preg-split-in-unicode-mode-delim-capture-not-working)

I have this text:

> 一个忠心的基督徒女子曾经十分自卑，她这样说:“耶和华既然对我了如指掌，他肯定不会爱我、悦纳我?”你也曾有类似的感觉，认为自己不配得到上帝悦纳，甚至不值得他关心吗？那么，尼希米记13:31的话也许能够安慰你。

This:

```
$array = preg_split('/[。？！?!]/u', $str, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($array);
```

Gives me this:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  一个 忠心 的 基督徒 女子 曾经 十分 自卑 , 她 这样 说 : “ 耶和华 既然 对 我 了如指掌 , 他 肯定 不会 爱 我 、 悦 纳 我 
    [1] =>  ” 你也 曾有 类 似的 感觉 , 认为 自己 不配 得到 上帝 悦 纳 , 甚至 不值得 他 关心 吗 ? 那么 , 尼 希 米 记 13 : 31 的话 也许 能够 安慰 你 。
)
```

Notice that it doesn't split at the question mark and it doesn't capture the first delimiter (。）at the end of array[0].

How can I fix that?

Comment: Those are funny characters... (I mean the `。？！`, not the chinese writing).

Comment: I don't think there is a flag for mb_split that captures delimiters. Do you know how to capture delimiters with mb_split?